# How to receive broadcast packets & send data from UDP Port with boost::asio

Tags: c++, udp, client, boost-asio

I apologize in advance if the question has been previously answered, but I've searched and found nothing that helps me. 
I 'm trying to broadcast from a server to a set of clients listening for any message. When client receive broadcast message, it send an another message to the server.

```
                                                               .--------.
                                                              .--------.|
.--------. address: any                         address: any .--------.||
|        | port: any      /                  \    port: 8888 |        |||
| server |-( ----------->| address: broadcast |----------> )-| client ||'
|        |                \    port: 8888    /               |        |'
|        |                                                   |        |
'--------'-( <-----------  ( address: server ) <---------- )-'--------'
                           ( port: 8888 ?    )
```

**Server.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Server binds to any address and any port.
  ip::udp::socket socket(io_service,
                         ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 0));
  socket.set_option(boost::asio::socket_base::broadcast(true));

  // Broadcast will go to port 8888.
  ip::udp::endpoint broadcast_endpoint(ip::address_v4::broadcast(), 8888);

  // Broadcast data.
  boost::array<char, 4> buffer;
  socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), broadcast_endpoint);

  ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint; 
  std::size_t bytes_transferred = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), sender_endpoint);
  std::cout << "Server got " << bytes_transferred << " bytes." << std::endl;
}
```

**Client.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

int main()
{
  namespace ip = boost::asio::ip;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // Client binds to any address on port 8888 (the same port on which
  // broadcast data is sent from server).
  ip::udp::socket socket(io_service, 
                         ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 8888 ));

  ip::udp::endpoint sender_endpoint;

  // Receive data.
  boost::array<char, 4> buffer;
  std::size_t bytes_transferred = socket.receive_from(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), sender_endpoint);

  std::cout << "Client got " << bytes_transferred << " bytes." << std::endl;

  boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver resolver(io_service);
  boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver::query query(boost::asio::ip::udp::v4(), "localhost", "8888");
  boost::asio::ip::udp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
  boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint = *iter;
  socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), remote_endpoint);
}
```

`client` receive broadcat message, but `server` does not receive message sent by `client`.

Thanks in advance.